# Using rake db:seed with file uploads

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-s3, paperclip, seed

I have an app that uses Paperclip, and I am also using `rake db:seed` to generate some demo accounts that can be used to help bring in new users.

Part of the information these demo accounts should contain are access to profile photos and other files that would be hosted on Amazon S3.

A sample of one entry in the `seeds` file:

```
userdemo = User.find_or_create_by_login(:login => "demo",
    :email => user.email,
    :user_type => "admin",
    :password => "demo",
    :password_confirmation => "demo")
```

How can I create the above user along with a profile photo? This would include uploading a file from my hard drive to S3 and associating that file with this record. Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [unit test in rails - model with paperclip](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895092/unit-test-in-rails-model-with-paperclip)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest using uploading a fixture image, as per [this other SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895092/unit-test-in-rails-model-with-paperclip)